# C# Execute shell command in current terminal

Tags: c#, shell, terminal, execution

I have an C# Console Application that is runned from the terminal. My question is then how i execute shell commands such as `color a0`, `dir` or `ping 1.1.1.1` etc, **in the same terminal** (and/or get the output if needed)

I've only seen solutions that starts a new cmd.exe process and runs the desired commands in there and return the output, but I'd like to know *if* it is possible to keep the command execution in the same process.

So say when I call myprogam.exe in the console, I want it to change to console color to green.
What most people would do (me too in most cases) is to do it like:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = Color.Green;
```

But that only changes to text printed later on. Anyway, I want a solution like:

```
string command = "color a0";
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/c " + command; // The Command
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

But preforms the task in the same terminal as the program is running in.

Comment: You can get the output of various commands, but I don't believe you're able to interact with the window itself.

Comment: Okey, not even if there was a way to get a handle to the process and send commands that way?

Comment: You need to include the full path of the executable because the path environmental variable is not set.  dir is a built in command in cmd.exe and doesn't need a path.  Open a cmd.exe window and type >help cmd to get syntax of the commands.

Comment: Of what executable?